# Uploading and Downloading the files using MIT App inventor (Webview)

Tags: webview, app-inventor

Webview is perfectly fine but how can I download and upload the files in webview.
I have an application that is based on getting files but I cannot do it by using webview so what should I do anyone helps me here? Please!

Regards,
[HAMZA ZOHAIB](https://www.thetoparticles.com)

Answer (score 0):

try the custom webview extension
https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/customwebview-an-extended-form-of-web-viewer/9934?u=taifun
and for follow up questions please ask in that thread